# Unicenta TCP/IP Card Reader Communication

Tags: tcp, cardreader, unicenta

I would like to ask if there are any available solutions (either from unicenta or 3rd party) where you provide the IP of a card reader and a TCP connection is initiated between unicenta POS system and the card reader?

I have tried to look for similar posts on here and haven't found something so if this was answered somewhere else I apologise in advance for the duplicate entry.

I've looked at the existing solutions and haven't found something similar so far.

If the unicenta version is needed, it is 4.6.4.

I am trying to have the unicenta POS software communicate with the card reader via TCP/IP.